# yii2 captcha image doesn't show

Tags: php, yii2

i have the following code in yii2 but the captcha image doesn't show !
controller:

```
 public function actions() {
    return [
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            'foreColor' => 0xF9AF21,
            'maxLength' => 5,
            'minLength' => 3,
            'padding' => 5,
            'offset' => 1,
            'transparent' => true,
            'height' => 40
        ],
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
    ];
}
```

model :(rules)

```
['verifyCode', 'captcha',],
```

view:

```
$form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className()])
```

[image: the login page]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **SiteController** look for **behaviors()** function, it might look like in the example bellow.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

You will not see *captcha image*, if in your **behaviour()** function wouldn't be specified `'only'` actions, like this: `'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],`. This line says that apply access rules only to this actions. If you don't want to add rules to specific actions, you can add `'captcha'` action to your rules, like in example below.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['signup', 'captcha'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            'foreColor' => 115006,
            'backColor' => 333333,
            'height' => 30,
            'maxLength' => 4,
            'minLength' => 4,
            'offset' => 2,
            'testLimit' => 1,
        ],
    ];
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [            
         ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],        
    ];
}
```

**View:**

```
use yii\captcha\Captcha;

<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::classname()) ?>
```

Comment: did that the problem exist!

Comment: your model this line remove `['verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction' => 'site/captcha'],` ??

Answer (score 0):

remove this function in site controller and the problems solved:

```
    public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```